# Artifactory access Illegal base64 character 3c error

Tags: tomcat, artifactory

I'm a newbie artifactory user. Today I updated artifatory to 5.4.1 version and after start it will crash. The Tomcat is running but it returns 503 error.

The error is:

```
2017-06-26 08:39:51,072 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.v.c.v.AccessTokenSettingsRenameToAccessClientSettingsConverter:19) - Starting to convert AccessTokenSettings to AccessClientSettings
2017-06-26 08:39:51,073 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.v.c.v.AccessTokenSettingsRenameToAccessClientSettingsConverter:42) - Finished to convert AccessTokenSettings to AccessClientSettings
2017-06-26 08:39:51,073 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.v.c.v.YumEnableFilelistsIndexingForExistingLocalReposConverter:19) - Starting The Yum local repositories conversion, to enable existing local repositories to calculate filelists.xml
2017-06-26 08:39:51,074 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.v.c.v.YumEnableFilelistsIndexingForExistingLocalReposConverter:23) - Finish The Yum local repositories conversion, to enable existing local repositories to calculate filelists.xml
2017-06-26 08:39:51,316 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:472) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8081/access (bundled) source: detected
2017-06-26 08:39:51,598 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:233) - Waiting for access server...
2017-06-26 08:39:51,839 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:243) - Got response from Access server after 240 ms, continuing.
2017-06-26 08:39:52,039 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:97) - Application could not be initialized: Illegal base64 character 3c
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:222) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$2(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:184) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:93) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.4.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to fetch and save root certificate from the access server.
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:230) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:114) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.1.jar:na]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to fetch and save root certificate from the access server.
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.fetchAndSaveAccessRootCertificate(AccessClientBootstrap.java:63) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.<init>(AccessClientBootstrap.java:41) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:227) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:216) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:211) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76) ~[artifactory-storage-common-5.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.init(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:228) ~[artifactory-core-5.4.1.jar:na]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientException: Failed to parse fetched root X509 certificate bytes in base64
        at org.jfrog.access.client.cert.CertClientImpl.getRootCertificate(CertClientImpl.java:33) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.fetchAndSaveAccessRootCertificate(AccessClientBootstrap.java:51) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3c
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.jfrog.access.client.cert.CertClientImpl.getRootCertificate(CertClientImpl.java:29) ~[access-client-core-2.0.0.jar:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

How can I solve this issue? What is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the Artifactory version you upgraded from?
Are there any other errors in other logs? Check specifically the following files:
* `$ART_HOME/access/logs/access.log`
* `$ART_HOME/tomcat/logs/localhost.<date>.log`
* `$ART_HOME/tomcat/logs/calatina.<date>.log`
Add here any log entries that you think might help to understand the root cause.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I upgraded from 5.3.2 to 5.4.1. Inside access.log file no error exist, only a WARN about YodaTime. I published log [here](https://pastebin.com/eQe45TrN). In localhost.<date>.log no error is printed, only info level logs. Finally, I published catalina<date>.log [here](https://pastebin.com/5FjRgSFu)

Comment: Try to do the following REST call and then try to decode the response body as base64: `curl http://localhost:8081/access/api/v1/cert/root`. This is a public http get request that returns the root certificate bytes encoded in base64. Decoding the response body is what fails for you.

Comment: I made the http request and got a base64 string, and its decoding failed. So is the certificated tampered? How can I solve this?

Comment: It doesn't look like the certificate is tempered because before its bytes are being sent (in base64) the certificate is read successfully. Instead, let's check the encoding part. Can you check what is the default encoding used by Tomcat (by the JVM)? Please also paste here the headers of the response you got, specifically the `Content-Type`. And few more questions - did you customize your tomcat in some way? Which JRE are you using? Which OS?

Comment: The default encoding used by Tomcat is UTF-8.
 
The headers of response are: Connection →close
Content-Language →en
Content-Length →1062
Content-Type →text/html;charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 28 Jun 2017 06:41:33 GMT
Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1

Tomcat is not customize but I have in the same server gitlab and artifactory so in Apache I configured 2 virtual hosts
1.8.0 JRE 64 bit
SO: Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03

Comment: It looks strange that the content type of the response is `text/html;charset=utf-8`, it should be `text/plain`, but I don't think that's the cause... If you can, please paste both the base64 value you get in the response and the content of the `$ART_HOME/access/keys/root.crt` file (it's in PEM format). I want to try to reproduce it. If you want you can regenerate the `root.crt` and `private.key` afterwards (follow https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens#AccessTokens-Troubleshooting > "... private key fingerprints mismatch", just delete those files first...).